# How to Get Client Login Auth Token for C2DM In Android

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I am presently developing push notifications in android.
I get registration id from C2DM,but i how can i get client login auth token,how to  write server side coding to send messages in php.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try curl:

curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -d accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE -d Email=[Email] -d Passwd=[Password] -d service=ac2dm -d source=[CompanyName-Project-Version]

Therefor you can use the PHP functions curl_init(), curl_setopt() and curl_exec()

hope that helps...